# Count tandem repeats in Perl

Tags: perl, count, substring

I am trying to write a code that given this string:

"TTGCATCCCTAAAGGGATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCTTTGTGATCAA"

finds consecutive repeats (alias [*tandem repeats*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_repeat)) of substring ATC, count them and if higher than 10 output the message "Off"

Here is my code:

```
my @count = ($content =~ /ATC+/g);
print @count . " Repeat length\n";

$nrRepeats = scalar(@count);    
if ($nrRepeats>10) {
    print("Off\n");
}
else {
    print("On\n");
}
```

Complications:
It counts all ATC substrings present in the string instead of only tandem repeats of ATC.

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: What does it mean "_consecutive repeats_"  vs  "_tandem repeats_"?

Comment: Sorry..it is the same concept

Comment: How many repeats should that sample string have? 8 or 1? (In other words, are you counting just the number of times ATCATC shows up, or the number of times 2 or more consecutive ATC substrings show up?)

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little ambiguous. I'm going to answer each interpretation separately.

1. If you're trying to determine whether the string contains a run of more than 10 ATCs in a row, you can use

   ```
   if ($content =~ /ATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATC/)
   ```

   This regex can be written more compactly as

   ```
   if ($content =~ /(?:ATC){11}/)
   ```
2. If you're trying to count the number of occurrences of at least 2 ATCs in a row, you can use

   ```
   my $count = () = $content =~ /(?:ATC){2,}/g;
   if ($count > 10)
   ```

   (See [`perldoc -q count`](https://perldoc.pl/perlfaq4#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string?).)

Comment: @Wolf, [There are multiple matches](https://pastebin.com/wdD3unxx). Subsequent evaluations of `//g` in scalar context will proceed where the last one left off. Did you accidentally make a single long chain of repeated `ATC`?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, it's obviously a [**really poor spec**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56490884/1) that we are working on. And OP is not very responsive/cooperative.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `/ATC+/g` is looking for `AT` followed by one or more `C` I suspect that what you want is this

```
/(ATC(?:ATC)+)/g
```

Which is ATC followed by one or more ATC

Comment: This would count every time ATC is repeated in the input not only consecutive.

Comment: Good hint. @RebiKirl if this actually helped you, think about **accepting** this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is a quite **repetition-aware** programming language that has been created to overcome repetitive manual work. So you can write strings that repeat a pattern as `$pattern x $repetitions` or literally type `'ATC'x11`.

Besides matching via `/(?:ATC){11}/` ([as already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56491417/2932052)), this would be another way to just get *Off*:

```
print "Off\n" if $content =~ ("ATC" x 11);
```

As to match all tandem repeats of `ATC` *and* trigger on those with more than 10 repetitions,<sup>[1]</sup> you need to loop explixitly:

```
while ($content =~ /(ATC(?:ATC)+)/g) {
    my $count = (length $1) / 3;
    print "$count repeat length\n";
    print "Off\n" if $count > 10;
}
```

Otherwise, for inputs such as `$prefix.ATCx2.$infix.ATCx11.$postfix` the detection would stop at the first tandem repeat. The predefined reference to the [captured match `$1`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is used to check the match length.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> following counts appearances of `ATC` in total, ignoring if they are consecutive:

```
my $count = () = $content =~ /ATC/g;
print "count (total matches) $count\n";
```

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I'm a bit slow today. I tried to find out meanwhile (and succeeded). What kept me exploring was a confusing forever loop with `while ($str.$str =~ /PAT/g) { ... }`

Comment: @ikegami fixed. Although `{2,}` now looks less repetitive to me ;) - also `while` would be better if there was another `ATCx2` before the actual `ATCx11`...

Comment: @ikegami the loop is indispensable, maybe this should be explained with some more text. Again: thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
# The string with the text to match
my $content = "TTGCATCCCTAAAGGGATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCTTTGTGATCAA";
# Split the text in every point preceded or followed by ATC
my @array = split /(?:(?<=ATC)|(?=ATC))/, $content;
# Creates an array which first element is 0 to contain every number of consecutives matches of ATC
my @count = 0;
for (@array) {
    if (/^ATC$/) {
# If ATC matches $_ increment by one the number of matches
        $count[-1]++;
    } else {
# If not and the script is counting a previous ATC sequence 
# we reset the counter adding a new element
        $count[-1] != 0 and push @count, 0;
    }
}
# Initialices $max and $index to 0 and undef respectively
my ($max,$index) = (0, undef);
for (keys @count) {
# If $max has less value than the current iterated sequence 
# $max is updated to current value and so is $index
    $max < $count[$_] and ($max, $index) = ($count[$_], $_);
}
# $index won't be defined if no value of ATC exists
defined $index and print "$max Repeat length\n";
# prints Off is the max match is greater or equal than 10
print(($max>=10?'Off':'On')."\n");
```

I think this is a good way since it allows you to know more data like the number of times is repeated.

EDIT: Updated with comments.

Comment: Can I know what is bad with the code to be downvoted? The number it returns is correct and also the output.

Comment: You don't explain what this code is supposed to do. The code itself is not easy to understand, either.

Comment: @melpomene I have update the answer explaining better what the script does, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Those comments are useless. They only explain what's apparent from the code anyway.

Comment: @Wolf I have tried to present the data as the question owner did. To do so I had to store the number of repetitions of every sequence of ATC in order to get the greater sequence. I do not see other way, but you are welcome to point me a better way to do it or create a new improved answer.

Comment: Slight correction: At least one of the comments is wrong. `my @count = 0` does not create an empty array.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of `split /(?:(?<=ATC)|(?=ATC))/` is, but I suspect it can be simplified to `split /(ATC)/`.

Comment: @melpomene I have corrected the comment and it cannot be simplified that way since I am trying to match a space beetween characters, the way you say would imply every ATC group disappears just like when you do `split /\s+/, @array`.

Comment: @melpomene For me it's useless to discuss `split` if `/(?:ATC){11}/` is the exact answer Perl has for this question.

Comment: Ah, no. The problem with `split /(ATC)/` is that it creates extra empty groups *between* adjacent ATCs.

Comment: @Wolf This response won't allow to  know the number the matches as the op wants, see the `print @count . " Repeat length\n";` part.

Comment: The whole thing can probably be simplified to `use List::UtilsBy qw(max_by); my @count = map length($_) / length('ATC'), $content =~ /(?:ATC)+/g; my $index = max_by { $count[$_] } 0 .. $#count; my $max = $count[$index];`

Comment: @melpomene Your response is pretty cool, why don't you post it? (I would never think doing it that way)

Comment: @sergiotarxz this is a valid argument. I concentrated too much on the On/Off question. It's not clear whether OP needs the exact count of consecutive repeats; to me. it looked like a "workaround" for Perl's `{}` feature.